# How to create reusable redux-module?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

For example, my app contains the two list: colors & my favorite colors. How to create the re-usable filter-module for this two lists?

The problem is the actions in redux commiting into global scope, so filter-reducer for colors and filter-reducer for favorite colors reacting to the same actions.

I try something like high-order functions that receive the module-name and returned new function (reducer) where classic `switch` contain `module + action.type`.

But how make scoped actions or scoped selectors? Best-practise?

Maybe Redux-Toolkit can solve this problem?

[image: The high-order reducer]

High-order reducer

[image: Hight order action]

High-order action

[image: Hight order selector]

High-order selector

Answer (score 0):

[Well described here](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic)

Name your function like createFilter and add a parameter like domain or scope
after this in switch check it e.g

```
export const createFilters = (domain, initState) => {
  return (state = initState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {    
      case: `${domain}/${FILTER_ACTIONS.ADD_FILTER}`:
...
```

and for actions create something like this

```
const createFilterActions = (domain: string) => {
  return {
    addFilter: (keys: string[]) => {
      return {
        type: `${domain}/${FILTER_ACTIONS.ADD_FILTER}`,
        payload: keys
      }
    },
    updateFilter: (key: string, state: any) => {
      return {
        type: `${domain}/${FILTER_ACTIONS.FILTER_UPDATED}`,
        payload: { key, state }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: And while that page doesn't explicitly show RTK, you can (and should!) use RTK's `createSlice` API inside there rather than defining actions and reducers by hand.

Comment: So, reusable redux-module problem will solved by RTK?